# showing only posts from current user - Custom post - Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to show posts ( under a custom post type ) only posted by the current logged in user.I have used this code for `reservation` and `listings`

### Below here is the code

```
add_filter( 'parse_query', 'pre_order_posts_filter' );

function pre_order_posts_filter( $query ) {

    global $post_type;      

    if(is_admin()){
        $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
        if ( 'reservation' == $post_type ) {
            if ( in_array( 'shop_manager', $current_user->roles ) ) {
                $query->query_vars['meta_key'] = 'author_id';
                $query->query_vars['meta_value'] = $current_user->ID; 
                $query->query_vars['post_status'] = array('pending', 'publish');     
            }

        }
        elseif ( 'listings' == $post_type ) {

            if ( in_array( 'shop_manager', $current_user->roles ) ) {
                $query->query_vars['post_author'] = $current_user->ID;     
            }

        }
    }

}
```

Its working for `reservation` but not for `listings`.

Comment: Try dumping out the Post Type first to be sure what you are dealing with like so: `function pre_order_posts_filter($query) { global $post_type; var_dump($post_type);  exit; //REST OF THE CODE}`

Comment: Are you sure that the post type is `listings` and not just `listing`?

Comment: yes it is `listings` http://prntscr.com/dcb2oe